# Hide/Show Tab Pages C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

I've been trying so hard to show the tab pages, actually hide the tab pages is working but show i tried everything but nothing successfully here's the code:

this is how i call the form that the user puts his password:

```
private void adminToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Password pss = new Password();

    pss.Show();
}
```

this is the button that have to add the Tab-Page:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGo.Text))
    {
        lblErro.Text = "Type the password.";
        return;
    }

    if(txtGo.Text != Properties.Settings.Default.Pass)
    {
        lblErro.Text = "Incorrect password.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();

        MainForm main = new MainForm();

        main.operatorToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = false;

        main.adminToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = true;

        main.accountPermissionsAdm();

    }
}
```

this is the function i created to the account permissions when the user is admin:

```
public void accountPermissionsAdm()
{
    if (!settings)
        tabControl_Config.TabPages.Add(tabPage_Report);

    if (!pathLoss)
        tabControl_Config.TabPages.Add(tabPage_PathLoss);

    if (!instrument)
        tabControl_Config.TabPages.Add(tabPage_Instrument);

    if (!parameters)
        mainTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage_DefineParameters);

    if (!scenario)
        mainTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage_RunScenario);

    if (!customer)
        mainTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage_CustomerId);

    IntPtr h = this.tabControl_Config.Handle;

    tabControl_Config.TabPages.Insert(3, tabPage_RunCondition);

}
```

Comment: If you've got Visual Studio 2010 and above try using Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - after reading your edited question with more code:**

Few potential problems:

1. In `btnGo_Click` you are calling `this.Close();` which returns, so the rest of the code in this `else` statement is **unreachable**.
2. Even if you will not call `this.Close();`, the code has no practical meaning, as you are creating a new instance of `MainForm` but you didn't show it (either by calling `main.Show()` or `main.ShowDialog()`).
3. Not sure if that's the flow, but it looks like `Password` is a child of your main form (`MainForm`). If that's the case, you should change the behavior so that, for example (there are other approaches) `Password` will return some value (boolean for example) that the main form needs to be changed (insertion of `TabPage` etc.). The change then must be performed on the main form and not from other forms.

Please follow these guidelines and make the changes, or consider of a new design, as it seems very broken to me.

---

**Original answer (how to hide/show tab page)**

I'm afraid you can't hide `TabPage`. You will have to remove and add it again. For example, like this:

**Hide:**

```
this.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);
```

**Show:**

```
this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage1);
```

The reason is that the `Hide()` function will have no effect in this situation, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx):

> TabPage controls are constrained by their container, so some of the
>   properties inherited from the Control base class will have no effect,
>   including Top, Height, Left, Width, **Show**, and **Hide**.

Comment: yes, i didn't use Hide(), i used Remove(), but when i remove i cant add it anymore.

Comment: @Vinicius Where did you create `tabPage_RunCondition`? Did you get any exception when calling `this.tabControl_Config.TabPages.Add(tabPage_RunCondition);` ?

Comment: i am 'hiding' the tab-page on the main-form but when the user wants go on administrator mode opens a form and when the user type the password   and press the button ok, i have to show te tabpage: run-condition, but nothing successfully.

Comment: Do you create the TabPage using the designer or at runtime? I think that the code for the ok button press event could be helpful.

Comment: i created using designer here's the code of the button:

                MainForm main = new MainForm();

                main.operatorToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = false;

                main.adminToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = true;

                main.tabControl_Config.TabPages.Add(main.tabPage_RunCondition);

Comment: @Vinicius is the button contained in `MainForm` ? It looks like you are creating a new instance of your form, within the same form. As you are not calling `main.Show()` or `main.ShowDialog()` nothing will appear on your screen. If that is the case I think the design is somehow broken, try changing `main` to `this`.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and add the full code of your button_ok click event. Where is your call to `main.Show()` ?